# MATLAB: How to change color of imhist and size of window?

Tags: image, matlab, histogram

I have:

```
img = imread('pic.jpg','jpg');
r = img(:,:,1);
g = img(:,:,2);
b = img(:,:,3);

subplot(3,1,1);
imhist(r);
subplot(3,1,2);
imhist(g);
subplot(3,1,3);
imhist(b);
```

How can I change colors of the histogram to Red, Green and Blue?
How can I change size of window tha appears?

**EDIT:**
Luis Miguel's answer regarding size of window works, but what if I want just to change height of window and left other parameneters (x, y, width) unchanged?

Comment: You can find an example of this colored histograms in this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961971/how-do-i-re-implement-a-color-based-histogram-do-feature-extraction-based-on-col/3962867#3962867

Comment: That's nice but I have to use imhist.

Comment: I just realized that was your question as well, sorry ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Size of the window:
You can get and then set 'Position'.

```
pos = get(h,'Position');
pos(4) = pos(4) + 10; % changing height only
pos(2) = pos(2) - 10; % you probably would want that - just try
set(h, 'Position', pos);
```

Comment: You can do `pos(2)=max(pos(2)-10,0);` to prevent window's bottom to go out of screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of the histogram bars and their limit lines as mentioned in [MATLAB's reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html), like this:

```
h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(h,'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','w')
```

To change the window size by doing something like this:

```
h = figure(1);
set(h, 'Position', [x y width height])
```

Comment: It does not work for imhist. It works for hist. How can I do this?

Comment: You can try setting the size of the figure before actually plotting. Then when you plot it will occupy the figure window, I think.